# Generate c# classes from wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, wsdl

I want generate C# classes from wsdl url in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

WSDL url is:https://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

I used "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider" tool to generate C# class and got following error:

> Error: No code was generated.
>       If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services
>       or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.
>       Done.

Any solution will be appreciate.

Comment: _"this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. **Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.** "_ Did you verify?

Comment: Download the WSDL and all the related XSD files to your local and then re-try with the local version. It should work.

Comment: @Sunil I tried this solution and it didn't work.

Comment: Downvoters, unless you've worked with GDS and airlines in the past, stop right now. Airlines are too important to bother with such niceties as following established standards

Comment: @Ahmad1334 airlines play loose and fast with web standards. It may well be that the WSDL is invalid. Try svcutil.exe` to generate the classes. If you can and don't get any errors, you'll know it's a possible problem with .NET Core's WCF support. The good news is you can reuse the generated classes in your .NET Core project

Comment: @Ahmad1334 if `svcutil.exe` complains though, it could mean that the airline doesn't support SOAP or the WS-* standards. For example, Sabre doesn't, offering ebXML over SOAP instead. Other services, eg Farelogix don't even respect their own XSDs

Comment: Thanks @panagiotis-kanavos. Is there any solution?

Comment: @Ahmad1334 I guess there is no way around a "deep dive". You need to figure out whether you _can_ actually do what you intend with the data you get.

Comment: @Ahmad1334 another possibility is that the airline posts a WSDL that can only be consumed using the *older* ASMX stack which didn't follow the WS-* standards - they didn't exist back then. You can use the `Add Service Reference ...` window in an ASP.NET (not Core) application to add a service reference, choose Advanced and add a "Web Service".

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos, I do that in ASP.NET (not Core) and c# classess successfully generated, but in .NET Core there is no "System.Web.Services" library!

Comment: @Ahmad1334 oops, it's actually worse. The WSDL references the OpenTravel schemas but doesn't provide links to them. You can use `svcutil.exe` though with an *http* url to generate the proxy classes

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos, With svcutil.exe: Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

Comment: You can insert a corresponding service reference directly in MS Visual Studio! VS then creates the CS classes for you in the namespace specified (by you).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer**

Open a development command prompt and run to generate the proxy classes:

```
svcutil http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl
```

Notice that I used `http` instead of `https`. The server's certificate causes problems with `svcutil`. Copy the classes into your project folder.

Add `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` from NuGet to the project's dependencies. Since ASP.NET Core doesn't use `web.config` files, you may have to create the bindings yourself when creating the proxy class, eg :

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
var address = new EndpointAddress("http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices");
var client = new AAResWebServicesClient((Binding)binding, address);
```

In the bindings, `BasicHttpsBinding` is used since no airline will accept unencrypted connections. Sabre requires TLS 1.2 or greater.

**Explanation**

Airlines and GDSs aren't great at following web interoperability standards. They are big enough that if there are any changes, it's the travel agent that has to accomodate them. Once they specify *their* standard, they don't care to change it either.

The OTA standard and Sabre's implementation for example were created in 2003 using ebXML, an alternative proposal to SOAP that didn't become a standard. Then they used ebXML over SOAP using mechanisms that didn't become part of the later SOAP standards. When the WS-* standards were created to fix the mess and ensure interoperability, they didn't even bother.

The WSDL you provided is similar to Sabre's. It uses *some* of OTA's operations like OTA_PING and adds custom ones. Fortunately, it doesn't include any tool-breakers like anonymous inner types.

You *could* use wsdl.exe to create an ASMX proxy, using the pre-2008 .NET stack. This hasn't been ported to .NET Core as far as I know though. *Maybe* it's part of the Windows Compatibility pack. After all, it *is* non-compliant and deprecated 10 years ago. ASMX hasn't had any significant upgrades in ages either. I *have* run into concurrency issues with deserializers in the past, when using ASXM services eg with Amadeus.

And then, there are those that won't even respect their own XSDs, eg Farelogix. They may return out-of-range values for enumerations and say "well, the XSD is for information purposes only". The `wsdl` file is clearly marked `not for production use`

There's no generic solution unfortunately. Here are some options:

- `wsdl.exe` and ASMX are out of the question if you want to use .NET Core. You'll have to switch to the Full framework if you have to use them.
- Create WCF *individual* proxies for each service. The size of the files is a lot smaller and you avoid clashes between types like Airport that are used by multiple services with slight variations or even incompatibilities.
- Use Fiddler or another tool to capture the requests and responses. Use these as templates to create plain HTTP GET requests. It's a dirty solution but *could* prove quicker and ever more reliable if you can't trust the provider's WSDL and XSDs

**WARNING**

Making the call doesn't mean that you can communicate with the provider. One of the main problems with ebXML over SOAP is that the body is OK but the *headers*, including those used for authentication are all wrong. This means that one has to create the authentication element

Another issue is that authentication fields are often misused eg using authentication headers we'd consider *session* tokens. GDSs still use mainframes and those session tokens often map to actual terminal sessions.

This means that one has to create authentication headers manually instead of relying on WCF to generate them. It also means that transactions are stateful - one has to keep track of which session was used for that reservation in order to book it, make sure all previous transactions are complete before starting a new one etc.

Comment: Thanks a million, It works.

Comment: very detailed and nice explanation.

Comment: That's my pain talking. I'm working with Farelogix right now and just discovered *they changed the info they return for refunds for different dates* ! Even when called today

Comment: We followed these steps & it seemed to be working great. But when trying to actually use the client, we are getting the error `Entry point was not found`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Download your WSDL files to local. Then, run the following command:

```
wsdl.exe /verbose /namespace:Air /out:D:\t\ar /protocol:SOAP /language:CS C:\path\to\wsdl\AAResWebServices_1.wsdl
```

Change namespace to a namespace of your choice.

WSDL.exe is part of your Windows SDK:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
```

Mine was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`

This generated the classes without any issues. I tested this solution.

Comment: `wsdl.exe` is used for *ASMX* services. Those classes aren't part of .NET Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I genuinely haven't checked what is / isn't available for "Core" here - but presumably `svcutil.exe` is preferable?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, but the pain is elsewhere. Airlines are too big to bother with such niceties as following standards. Explained in my answer

Comment: @MarcGravell this Q is a great example of questions that may look bad but aren't if you know the business