# 'Entry point was not found' Error using classes generated from WSDL file

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

We are trying to use a 3rd party's SOAP API in our .NET Core Web App. We have tried 2 things to get the classes generated from the WSDL file they provided us.

1. Using WCF in Visual Studio
2. Using svcutil directly as recommended in the 'Short Answer' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358678/generate-c-sharp-classes-from-wsdl)

In both cases, Visual Studio recognizes the classes, provides the expected intellisense & the solution builds successfully. We added the `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` nuget as well, as suggested in the link in #2.

However, when we attempt to call any method on the client we get the error 'Entry point was not found'.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
var address = new EndpointAddress("{SOAP Endpoint Address}");
var client = new ItemDefinitionServiceEndpointClient(binding, address);

var response = await client.findAllAsync(); // This throws the 'Entry point was not found' error
```

[image: Error from Visual Studio]

How can we resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After a day & a half, I discovered I needed to update the `System.ServiceModel` nuget packages in my project.

Comment: Have the problem been solved after updating the packages?

Comment: @Jiayao Yes, updating the packages resolved the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and noticed that I had updated 1 of the many "System.ServiceModel" nuget packages but not the others. Reverting the 1 update to make sure they are all on the same version fixed the issue.